# flask db migrate - OperationalError

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm trying to add a new column to my flask database using flask_migrate. However, when I try to migrate it returns an error. I've done pretty much every step to do a migration; installing flask_migrate, initializing the flask_migrate, do flask db init to create the migrations folder.

This is my **init**.py file

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'admin_login'

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('BLOG_SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('YVES_LETTERS_DATABASE_URI')


from letters import routes
```

models.py file (the views column is the new column I'm trying to add to the database)

```
from letters import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime import datetime

class Data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    views = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'id: {self.id}, title: {self.title}, author: {self.author}, date: {self.date_added}'
```

The error messages

```
C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:852: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  'Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. '
C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:873: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1803, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: data.views

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\Scripts\flask-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 425, in decorator
    with __ctx.ensure_object(ScriptInfo).load_app().app_context():
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\yves-letters-2\run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from letters import app
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\yves-letters-2\letters\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from letters import routes
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\yves-letters-2\letters\routes.py", line 5, in <module>
    from letters.forms import Login, Letter, Register, Confirmation, Edit, Filter
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\yves-letters-2\letters\forms.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Filter(FlaskForm):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\yves-letters-2\letters\forms.py", line 63, in Filter
    years = SelectField('Year', choices=get_years())
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\yves-letters-2\letters\forms.py", line 43, in get_years
    for data in Data.query.all():
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2759, in all
    return self._iter().all()
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2897, in _iter
    execution_options={"_sa_orm_load_options": self.load_options},
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1692, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1614, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 326, in _execute_on_connection
    self, multiparams, params, execution_options
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1491, in _execute_clauseelement
    cache_hit=cache_hit,
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1846, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2027, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1803, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\flask_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: data.views
[SQL: SELECT data.id AS data_id, data.title AS data_title, data.content AS data_content, data.author AS data_author, data.status AS data_status, data.date_added AS data_date_added, data.views AS data_views
FROM data]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

At the end of the error messages, it says "no such column: data.views" which is true because it's the column I'm trying to migrate. But why did this happen?

Comment: Can you add in the command and the migration file that you're using to 'apply' the migration?

Comment: @Doobeh What command and which migration file? Is it the one that's being created inside the /migrations/versions folder every time a migration occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are using an SQLite database here. This database is very limited in terms of making changes to the database schema. It is not uncommon that it may fail to upgrade or downgrade a table.

Since this has already occurred, you can delete the migration that has caused this. Then follow the steps below to generate migrations that work better.

Unfortunately, there is no simpler way to get around this. The only available method is to generate a brand new table with the new table structure. During the new migration, you can initialize batch mode.

```py
migrate = Migrate(app, db, render_as_batch=True)
```

Then regenerate the migration again.

```py
$ flask db migrate -m '<your table>'
$ flask db upgrade
```